# Open an Access Form to a specific record selected from an excel sheet cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am working on a work issue that I was tasked with.  In an excel sheet there is a list of IDs and an MS Access database with records that correspond to these records.  I need to write code to open an Access Form to the record identified from the excel field.

```
Sub OpenAccess()

   Dim LPath As String
   Dim StudentID As Integer

   'Path to Access database
   LPath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CNRC_Test.accdb"

   'Open Access and make visible
   Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
   oApp.Visible = True

   'Open Access database as defined by LPath variable
   oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase LPath

   'Open form called Categories filtering by CategoryID

   oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "Student Details", , , "Student ID=" & StudentID


End Sub
```

I have tried this code:

```
Sub OpenAccess()

   Dim LPath As String
   Dim StudentID As Integer

   'Path to Access database
   LPath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CNRC_Test.accdb"

   'Open Access and make visible
   Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
   oApp.Visible = True

   'Open Access database as defined by LPath variable
   oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase LPath

   'Open form called Categories filtering by CategoryID

   oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "Student Details", , , "Student ID=" & StudentID


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? describe the error or what issues do you have? also, what excel and access version are you working with?

Comment: Office 2016 the code opens the access form but not by clicking an excel cell or going to the record specified by the excel cell.  I am needing to open the access form to the record specified by the excel cell that is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

> oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "Student Details", , , "Student ID=" & StudentID

Testing on Office 16:  If "Student Details" is the name of your form, and the Record Source of your form is the table you want to source from, and "Student ID" is the index number column, and there's a text field on your form with a Control Source that is the name of either that index number column or some other column in the table, then there should be one record returned (with a result in the text box).

An example follows:

First, rewrite your function def at top as `OpenAccess(StudentID)`.

Next, make the assignment of StudentID from within the sheet you want to use:

Fill B3 with an index value of your choice.

Then temporarily park the active cell in A1.

Then bring up the Sheet object from within Microsoft Excel Objects in your VBAProject tree in the left VBE pane.  Write this into its module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
  Call OpenAccess(Target.Value)
 End If
End Sub
```

Then click into B3.

Comment: StudentID needs come from click event/ value in the excel document and open corresponding record in access.

Comment: Are things working now, or is this a missing pipeline?

Comment: I am still looking for assistance in coding a way to achieve the following: StudentID needs come from click event/ value in the excel document and open corresponding record in access

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste this code behind the Excel worksheet module and customize it to fit your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim studentID As Long

    ' Exit if selection is more than one cell
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Validate if selected cell is in range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1:A5"), Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Assign studentid value from current cell
        studentID = Target.Value

        ' Call the open procedure with current cell value
        Call OpenAccess(studentID)

    End If

End Sub


Sub OpenAccess(studentID As Long)


    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim LPath As String


    'Path to Access database
    LPath = "C:\Temp\Test.accdb"

    ' Check if Access is open
    On Error Resume Next
        Set oApp = GetObject(LPath)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oApp.Visible = True

    'Open form called Categories filtering by CategoryID
    oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "Student Details", , , "[Student ID]=" & studentID


End Sub
```

Comment: Runs opens access and closes immediately

Comment: did you adjust the path to the DB?

Comment: Can you edit / update your question with your current code?